# css border-radius is not applied

Tags: css

CSS border radius is not applied on navigation wrapper. Any ideas why?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDEmS/)

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div><a href="">Home</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Products</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Services</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Support</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Contact</a></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.navigation {   
    position:relative;
    float:left;

    overflow:auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.navigation div {
    position:relative;
    float:left;

    background: #484745;

    height:53px;
    line-height: 53px;
}
```

Comment: In what browser are you testing?

Comment: Yes it is applied – you just don't see it, as the element with rounded corners didn't have a border nor a background. Check which element you really want to have rounded corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `background-color` to `.navigation`. Write like this:

```css
.navigation {    
    background: #484745;
}
```

Check this: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nDEmS/1/)

Comment: Ahhhh thanks, I did not realize that the border is actually applied to the element itself, but not to its child elements...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your background. Your divs' background hide border radius of `.navigation`. Just add background to `.navigation` (see http://jsfiddle.net/nDEmS/18/)